# Need Help for better practice Jquery codes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make my jquery codes look better here. My functions are working correctly but I was wondering if anyone can make my codes less ugly. Thanks a lot!

**HTML**

```
<div class='image_layout'>
    <a href='#'><img src=' a.jpg '/></a> 
          <br><p class='credits'>hahahah 
          <br>Agency: Agency1
          <br>Picture ID: 5 </p> 
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#image_layout').on('hover', 'img', function() {
    $(this).parent().next().next().fadeIn('fast');
})
$('#image_layout').on('mouseout', 'img', function() {
    $(this).parent().next().next().fadeOut('fast');
})​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass two functions to jQuery hover - one for mousein, one for mouseout. You can make this change as long as you don't have dynamically added images. Your code would also be a lot simpler if the element you are fading has an ID or class:

```
$('#image_layout img').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).closest('.someClass').fadeIn('fast');
    },
    function () {
        $(this).closest('.someClass').fadeOut('fast');
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `.eq` as opposed to two `next` statements, additionally, hover takes two functions, the first being for the `mouseenter` event, and the second for `mouseout`

```
$('#image_layout').hover('hover', 'img', function () {
    $(this).parent().eq(2).fadeIn('fast');
}, function () {
    $(this).parent().eq(2).fadeOut('fast');
})
```

**References**

- [Take a look at `eq` here](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)
- [Read over `hover` here](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Comment: You can't pass two callback functions to `on()`, only `hover()` does that.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.image_layout').on('hover', 'img', function (e) {
    if(e.type == 'mouseover') {
        $(this).closest('.image_layout').find('.credits').stop().fadeIn('fast');
    } else {
        $(this).closest('.image_layout').find('.credits').stop().fadeOut('fast');
    }
})
```

You could also have done:

```
$('.image_layout').on('hover', 'img', function() {
    $(this).closest('.image_layout').find('.credits').stop().fadeIn('fast');
}, function() {
    $(this).closest('.image_layout').find('.credits').stop().fadeOut('fast');
});
```

If you're sure that nothing other than hovering the image will cause the element to fade, you could simply write:

```
$('.image_layout').on('hover', 'img', function() {
    $(this).closest('.image_layout').find('.credits').stop().fadeToggle('fast');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into [Douglas Crockford's JS Style Guide](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html). He'd make your code look something like (with improvements):

```
var obj = $('#image_layout img');
obj.mouseover( function(){
  $(this).parent([selector]).next([selector]).fadeIn('fast');
});

obj.mouseout( function(){
    $(this).parent([selector]).next([selector]).fadeOut('fast');
});
```

You don't need the `on`, just call the function directly.